# Regex Replace c#

Tags: c#, regex, replace, code-duplication

```
string formattedFormula = Regex.Replace("A1+A1", "(?!A1\\d+)[A1]" , "{" + 0 + "}");
```

I need the result as {0}+{0}. But this code replaced like this {0}{0}+{0}{0}

this is just an example.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class HelloWorld
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       string formattedFormula = Regex.Replace("A1+A1", "(?!A1\\d+)[A1]" , "{" + 0 + "}");
        Console.WriteLine (formattedFormula);
    }
}
```

My Real code is

```
foreach (string columnCode in parameters)
            {
                string pattern = string.Empty;

                if (!Common.Common.IsNumaric(columnCode))
                {
                    pattern = "(?!" + columnCode + "\\d+)[" + columnCode + "]";

                    stringList.Add(columnCode);
                    incrementor++;

                    formattedFormula = Regex.Replace(formattedFormula, pattern, "{" + incrementor.ToString() + "}");
                }
                else
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }
```

[image]

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: Does this _need_ to be regex? Is your input always "Letter Number Plus Letter Number"?

Comment: Why are you always printing "0", and always matching specifically "A1"?

Comment: @gunr2171 This is just an example.

Comment: You didn't answer my first two questions, so I'm going to assume that your input format is as I described, your expected output for your example is `{A1}+{A1}`, and regex is not needed.

Comment: @gunr2171 my expected output is {0}+{0}

Comment: So then `return "{0}+{0}";` is all the code you need. Please, be more clear about your inputs and outputs. I have no idea what you're actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: @gunr2171 I have updated with the real code.

Comment: Try `pattern = $@"\b(?!{columnCode}\d){columnCode}\b";`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This pattern worked for my Scenario.

```
pattern = "(?:\\d+["+ columnCode + "]|["+ columnCode + "]+\\d)["+ columnCode + "\\d]*";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```cs
pattern = $@"\b(?!{columnCode}\d){columnCode}\b";
```

See the [resulting regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2xPYNm/1). It matches

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?!A1\d)` - fail the match if there is `A1` + a digit
- `A1` - a fixed text
- `\b` - a word boundary.